# Moving JavaScript inside HTML file causes problem with hover

Tags: javascript

I have separate .js, .css, and .html files that I need to merge together into a single HTML file in order to deploy into IBM Connection.

However, after adding the JavaScript into the file the hover function isn't working any more.

[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/gurusworld2013/pen/LgLwgd)

JavaScript:

```
$("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display','none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top',e.pageY-$('#info-box').height()-30);
  $('#info-box').css('left',e.pageX-($('#info-box').width())/2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if(ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(link,'_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

I can't post the HTML as it has too many characters.

Comment: could you post error messages?

Comment: your codepen link is not working

Comment: the link should work. I tried and it works. https://codepen.io/gurusworld2013/pen/LgLwgd
The error is that the hover function is not working anymore. Map and color etc. is working properly.

Comment: The hover function is working for me, I move the mouse over the country and I get a State/Capital box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the codes were correct. I have forgotten just the script ending ">"
that why it didn't recognize as script.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can place js code inside of 
    `<script><script>`
tag (see https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_scripts.asp) and css inside of

`<head>
  <style>
  your css
  </style>
<head>`

Comment: I informed already that I know this scheme. this does not help